# AngularJs tooltip initialization and fade out

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-strap

I use angular-ui tooltips (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js) or angular strap tooltip (http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/tooltips#tooltips)

I need show tooltip on element, when the some event or expression.

Example below, we have the input. And i need to show tooltip, when data.model.count == 5. And then hide tooltip of beyond the 5 second. Help me please!

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.model">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a directive! [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wN2jhTRgYXkeCKdIZA5P?p=preview)

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('showTip', function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      showTip: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attr){
      var tooltip;
      scope.$watch('showTip', function(newVal){
        if(newVal == 5){
          tooltip.css({visibility: 'visible'});
          $timeout(function(){
            tooltip.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
          }, 5000)
        }
      })

      elm.bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
        tooltip = elm.find('div');
        tooltip.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
      })
    }
  }
});
```